# Unresolved external sysmbols in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a VS2010 DLL project. It  works fine. I added another project into this. But now I am getting

> 40 error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol: Scan                Trigger.def
>
> 41 error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol: Setup               Trigger.def
>
> 42 error LNK1120:2 unesolved external                            Trigger.lib

Trigger.def is defined as

> LIBRARY
>
> EXPORTS
>
> > Setup @1
> >
> > TearDown @2
> >
> > Scan @3

I think I need to set up something in linker, since inclusion of another project messed up order of things, But I do not know what?

Thank you

Comment: Well, those symbols don't actually exist.  Probably because their real names are decorated, like _Setup@0 or a C++ mangled name.  Use the linker's /MAP option to see what they really look like.

Comment: They are defined as routines like "int __stdcall TearDown()", int __stdcall Setup(int etime, double svalue, double csvalue, double gain, int nImages, char* name). The program works without the added project.  How do you set up /MAP option in teh linker? I am using VS2010.

Comment: I set the "Generate MAP file " Otion as Yes (/MAP). and set a location and a name for the test.Map file. But I am not getting a MAP file anywhere!